# How to call FFI functions in react-native

Tags: react-native, ffi, javascriptcore

I have a Rust library that exposes a C-callable FFI. I want to be able to use it in React Native by building a Native Module for Android.

I'm looking into `jnr-ffi` for building the native module, but the documentation isn't very clear.

Can someone guide me how something like this would work? Are there any alternatives? E.g. something like `node-ffi` but for react-native where i don't need to build a native module at all?